# Synergy keyboard layout

Tags: 12.10, keyboard-layout, synergy

I have an issue with Synergy. I do really love how it works but when I leave my host PC with non-English layout I can't type anything on the secondary PC.

My host PC is Windows 7. I have English and Russian keyboard layouts.
My secondary PC is Ubuntu 12.10. I also have English and Russian keyboard layouts there.

The keyboard and mouse are connected to the host PC (Windows 7).

When the mouse cursor leaves the host PC with Russian layout the keyboard doesn't respond in the secondary PC. I can't type and can't change the layout.
The only way is to return the mouse cursor to the host PC, switch keyboard layout to English and go back to the secondary PC.
It's kind of annoying.

PS: I updated to the latest version (1.4.10) of Synergy with the same result.

So, is there way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should report a bug on the synergy tracker.